# Django views.py if statement not passing value to HTML File

Tags: python, django, if-statement

In my Django `views.py` page, I have some code, where the user enter an employee ID with an HTML form, that submits the value to `views.py`. Using that, I check whether the employee ID is in a database by iterating over each ID in the database, appending it to an empty `list`, and using an `if` statement.
The parts where I receive the employee ID is working fine, and so is the ID getting appended to the `list`. However, when I use an `if` statement to check whether the employee ID that was given is a part of the list, isn't working. Despite this working on Jupyter Notebook when i tested the same.

**Here's the code**: 
`views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pandas as pd


dat = pd.read_csv('/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Cakewala DB/CW_Attendance/AttendanceApp/test_employee.csv')

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    employee_id = request.POST.get('id')

    print(employee_id)

    id_list = []
    for id in dat["ID"]:
        id_list.append(id)

    print(id_list)

    if employee_id in id_list:
        print("yes")
        employee_row = dat.loc[dat["ID"] == employee_id]
        employee_name = employee_row.iat[0, 1]
        return render(request, 'attendance/index.html', {
            "employee_id": employee_id,
            "employee_name": employee_name
        })

    return render(request, 'attendance/index.html')
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Attendance - Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Cakewala Attendance</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="id">Employee ID</label> <br>
            <input type="number" name="id" max="9999" min="1000">
            <input type="submit" id="submit-btn"> <br>
            <p id="name">{{ employee_id }}: {{ employee_name }}</p>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`test_employee.csv`:

```
ID, NAME
1001, John Doe
1002, Jane Doe
```

`Command Line Output when I pass employee ID as 1001`:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 15, 2022 - 13:22:00
Django version 4.0.4, using settings 'CW_Attendance.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
1001
[1001, 1002]
[15/Apr/2022 13:33:17] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 598
```

I need to display the Employee ID and Name in the HTML file, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are not passing the context if employe id does not exists. Basically you are not passing the context in else condition while rendering the template. Also, sometimes, types will not match. Try converting both in to int. if int/str(employee_id) in id_list